# Using lm() in R (terminal) and Rstudio gives different outputs with the same input data

Tags: r

I'm fitting a linear model, for which I get different coefficients based on whether I use RStudio or R; even though I'm using the same input data and the same code in both cases.

I've tried different subsets of the data (from only 10 rows to up to half of the data), and the discrepancy only occurs when the entire dataset is inputted.

[Here's the dput() output](https://www.protectedtext.com/data19072019) (it was too big to paste it here, password: r )

```
a = dputdata
lm.transcprot = lm(formula = I(a$b - 0) ~ 0 + a$a)
```

**Session details:**

RStudio

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib/libopenblasp-r0.2.19.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C             
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.0   rsconnect_0.8.13 tools_3.6.0    

> find('lm')
[1] "package:stats"

> summary(a)
        a                 b   
 Min.   :  1.002   Min.   :     0.13   
 1st Qu.:  5.887   1st Qu.:  5320.27   
 Median : 14.551   Median : 11739.61   
 Mean   : 25.877   Mean   : 20524.21                     
 3rd Qu.: 34.424   3rd Qu.: 26430.47                     
 Max.   :136.997   Max.   :116315.41
```

Terminal

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.3.199/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/libmkl_rt.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1 tools_3.6.1   

> find('lm')
[1] "package:stats"

> summary(a)
        a                 b   
 Min.   :  1.002   Min.   :     0.13   
 1st Qu.:  5.887   1st Qu.:  5320.27   
 Median : 14.551   Median : 11739.61   
 Mean   : 25.877   Mean   : 20524.21                     
 3rd Qu.: 34.424   3rd Qu.: 26430.47                     
 Max.   :136.997   Max.   :116315.41
```

**Output obtained:**

RStudio

```
> lm.transcprot

Call:
lm(formula = I(a$b - 0) ~ 0 + a$a)

Coefficients:
a$a  
    462.5
```

Terminal

```
> lm.transcprot            

Call:
lm(formula = I(a$b - 0) ~ 0 + a$a)

Coefficients:
a$a  
     1889
```

Comment: Your `dput()` output looks incomplete (the last line is `27.254119, 72.870086, 65.291127, 5.71344, 62.268586, 2`)

Comment: Can you explain what the specification of the response variable as `I(a$protein.prot.expr  - 0)` is supposed to be doing?  How would this be expected to be different from simply `a$protein.prot.expr` ?

Comment: @akrun Indeed, apparently that hosting server has a cap limit inferior to the size of my dput() output

Comment: @BenBolker, that is supposed to be fixing the intercept value to (0,0)

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference, but do you get any different results from `lm.transcprot = lm(formula =protein.prot.expr ~ 0 + rna.tpm, data=a)` ?

Comment: @BenBolker the link should work now

Comment: @BenBolker I tried your suggestion, and the result keeps being different in both

Comment: when I try the [dput link above](https://www.protectedtext.com/data19072019) I get "Somebody already occupied this site, you can try different URL.
If this is your site enter the password."

Comment: @BenBolker yeah, I guess it's easy to oversee it, but next to the link I wrote the password: r

Comment: How are you reading in the data? Can we please see `str(a)` and/or `summary(a)` from both environments?  I get a slope of 462.5 no matter how I run it (Linux r-devel console, MacOS R 3.5.1 in console and RStudio)

Comment: @BenBolker summary() added, which is the same for both

Comment: OK, thanks.  Now results of `find("lm")` and `sessionInfo()` for both R and RStudio sessions? What if you use `stats::lm(...)` to make sure you're getting the correct version of `lm()`?  Are both results (especially your RStudio version) from clean sessions?

Comment: @BenBolker both find() and sessionInfo() added. I also tried using the function directly from the library, as you suggested, to no avail. Both results are indeed from clean sessions (for RStudio I clear the objects from the workspace). I'm really thankful for your time.

Comment: Something's rotten with your Rstudio session. I get the same result in both rstudio and R, and the coefficient is 462.5. Irrespective of that: *don't do that*. The data is not even close to normal, and you only get significance because of the thousands of data points. You will not get a reasonable model from this approach!

Comment: @January Indeed, I know the data is not correlated at all; and that is actually in part why I'm doing it (to compare it with another model). I guess you mean my Terminal R is the rotten one (?) (as RStudio is the one giving a similar result as yours). Even when trying to model in a logarithmic scale, the Terminal gives me a completely non-sense fitted line, while in RStudio it actually goes through the cloud of points.

Comment: @January: it's the terminal session, not the RStudio session, that's giving the OP a weird answer. As for whether this is sensible: I agree it's not a good mechanistic model, but it might not be an unreasonable summary of the data (depending entirely on context and how it's presented ...)

Comment: Oh, sorry, yea, your terminal. Regarding the other issue: the data shows a significant correlation (as you would expect with a couple of thousand protein / gene expression values). However, I would not use the model in any way.

Comment: maybe??? the MKL linear algebra library is doing something funny?? See https://github.com/eddelbuettel/mkl4deb (the very end explains how to switch your options back from MKL to the built-in BLAS ...)

Comment: @January It's true that I exaggerated saying there's no correlation whatsoever, but, as you said, a linear regression model is not good enough to be used as a model. My focus is on trying to find which data points would better align with the fundamental law of biology; and in my estimation, those would be the ones that are closer to a fitted linear regression model.

Comment: And what makes you assume a linear relationship? Also, no. Given that you set the intercept to 0, the lowest residuals will be for the genes with very low protein / RNA expression values. Also, the DNA->RNA->protein paradigm is not what I would call "*the* fundamental law of biology".

Comment: @January I assume that based on the paradigm, which would be 1-on-1. Of course, that's not the case with this data, 'cause both protein and RNA values do not represent their exact quantification cell-wise. A first intuition made me think that to represent the dogma, it would require the model to intercept at 0; although a second intuition reminds me that because of the nature of the data itself (a random sample of the molecules), that should not be the case. About the name, it is indeed not a law, but a [dogma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_dogma_of_molecular_biology).

Comment: Not only a "dogma", but (a) of molecular biology (and not of biology in general), and (b) it pertains only to the direction of the information flow and not to any kind of specific relationship between numbers of molecules. It never did. All that it ever said is that the information about the specific *sequence* of nucleotide acids of a gene cannot be transferred from protein to a nucleic acid again. Please read the Wikipedia article which you have cited, in especially the quote from Crick with which the article begins.

Comment: @January But, by definition, isn't there have to be a relationship between cause and consequence, even if it's not linear? That is why I understand such a relationship as implicit in the dogma itself. Will it be [correlated](https://rdcu.be/bLp4j)? Not in a general way, as it may differ substantially between different proteins (a lot of factors to take into account, which could be generally defined as a translation ratio); but there is a reason why researchers look into differentially expressed genes; as it may probably be causing an effect through a differential number of translated proteins

Comment: Yes, correlated in the widest sense, so maybe you can use spearman's rho, but using a linear regression model is asking for trouble. For example because of `Var(X) ~ x`. Try this: `x <- c(rnorm(10), 20) ; y <- c(rnorm(10), 20) ; summary(lm(y~x))`. Also, genes are not independent, not by far, so one of the central assumptions of the statistical analysis is violated in your approach. And yea, I am one of these researchers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196868/discussion-between-hart-radev-and-january).